# How can I change the Java Runtime Version on Windows (7)?

Tags: java, windows, registry, controls, panel

How can I change the Java Runtime Version on Windows.

I installed Java 7 for some tests, and now I need the old java6 as system default, but I don't want to uninstall the Java 7 (I need it for later tests). Can I change the system-used [JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) in the control panel/Java/JRE tab? I can change/edit/add/delete the user-used version, but not the system-used.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

For Java **applications**, i.e. programs that are delivered (usually) as `.jar` files and started with `java -jar xxx.jar` or via a shortcut that does the same, the JRE that will be launched will be the first one found on the `PATH`.

If you installed a JRE or JDK, the likely places to find the `.exe`s are below directories like  `C:\Program Files\JavaSoft\JRE\x.y.z`. However, I've found some "out of the box" Windows installations to (also?) have copies of `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` in `C:\winnt\system32` (NT and 2000) or `C:\windows\system` (Windows 95, 98). This is usually a pretty elderly version of Java: 1.3, maybe? You'll want to do `java -version` in a command window to check that you're not running some antiquated version of Java.

You can of course override the PATH setting or even do without it by explicitly stating the path to java.exe / javaw.exe in your command line or shortcut definition.

---

If you're running **applets** from the browser, or possibly also **Java Web Start applications** (they look like applications insofar as they have their own window, but you start them from the browser), the choice of JRE is determined by a set of registry settings:

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
Name: CurrentVersion
Value: (e.g.) 1.3
```

More registry keys are created using this scheme:

```
(e.g.) 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.3   
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.3.1
```

i.e. one for the major and one including the minor version number. Each of these keys has values like these (examples shown):

```
JavaHome    : C:\program Files\JavaSoft\JRE\1.3.1
RuntimeLib  : C:\Program Files\JavaSoft\JRE\1.3.1\bin\hotspot\jvm.dll
MicroVersion: 1
```

... and your browser will look to these settings to determine which JRE to fire up.

Since Java versions are changing pretty frequently, there's now a "wizard" called the "Java Control Panel" for manually switching your browser's Java version. This works for IE, Firefox and probably others like Opera and Chrome as well: It's the 'Java' applet in Windows' `System Settings` app. You get to pick any one of the installed JREs. I believe that wizard fiddles with those registry entries.

If you're like me and have "uninstalled" old Java versions by simply wiping out directories, you'll find these "ghosts" among the choices too; so make sure the JRE you choose corresponds to an intact Java installation!

---

Some other answers are recommending setting the *environment* variable `JAVA_HOME`. This is meanwhile outdated advice. Sun came to realize, around Java 2, that this environment setting is

1. unreliable, as users often set it incorrectly, and
2. unnecessary, as it's easy enough for the runtime to find the Java library directories, knowing they're in a fixed path relative to the path from which java.exe or javaw.exe was launched.

There's hardly any modern Java software left that needs or respects the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

---

More Information:

- http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/runtime_win32.html
- http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0604.html

...and some useful information on multi-version support:

- http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0604.html

Comment: The default Java7 wizard also installs java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe into C:\Windows\System32\ on Windows 7. This is not a legacy issue. Great answer anyway!

Comment: If you update your Java version you may find you are still using the old version if it is in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: @LucasHoepner - more recent versions of java install a stub to c:\windows\system32 that scans the system to identify the most recent installed version of java and invoke that.  You don't get a problem with them invoking an out-of-date version by default because of this copy.

Comment: Try `java -showversion` instead of `java -version`.

Comment: Very good and detailed answer, but missing the new best practice java introduces regarding path location switching. see [stackoverflow.com/questions/27996603](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996603/should-i-add-both-java-home-and-jre-home-in-environmental-variable-path/34733232#34733232).

Answer (score 58):

I use to work on UNIX-like machines, but recently I have had to do some work with Java on a Windows 7 machine. I have had that problem and this is the I've solved it. It has worked right for me so I hope it can be used for whoever who may have this problem in the future.

These steps are exposed considering a default Java installation on drive C. You should change what it is necessary in case your installation is not a default one.

## Change Java default VM on Windows 7

Suppose we have installed Java 8 but for whatever reason we want to keep with Java 7.

1- Start a cmd as administrator

2- Go to `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java`

3- Rename the current directory **javapath** to **javapath_<version_it_refers_to>**. E.g.: `rename javapath javapath_1.8`

4- Create a **javapath_<version_you_want_by_default>** directory. E.g.: `mkdir javapath_1.7`

5- cd into it and create the following links:

```
cd javapath_1.7
mklink java.exe "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"
mklink javaw.exe "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe"
mklink javaws.exe "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaws.exe"
```

6- cd out and create a directory link **javapath** pointing to the desired javapath. E.g.: `mklink /D javapath javapath_1.7`

7- Open the register and change the key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion** to have the value 1.7

At this point if you execute `java -version` you should see that you are using java version 1.7:

```
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

8- Finally it is a good idea to create the environment variable JAVA_HOME. To do that I create a directory link named CurrentVersion in C:\Program Files\Java pointing to the Java version I'm interested in. E.g.:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\
mklink /D CurrentVersion .\jdk1.7.0_71
```

9- And once this is done:

- Right click My Computer and select Properties.
- On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit/create JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, in that case, C:\Program Files\Java\CurrentVersion

Comment: @Mia Hi Mia, I tried this solution but i get the following error message when doing `java -version` : `Error : Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion has value '1.7' but '1.8' is required. Error : could not find java.dll. Error : Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment`

Comment: Hi @YassinHajaj, I don't know if I can be of much help, as I do not currently have this setup anymore. Anyway, it looks like there may be some problems on your path. Make sure you are not actually copying the files but creating soft links instead (step 5). The same goes to the `javapath` and `CurrentVersion` directories (steps 6 and 8). Good luck!

Comment: @Mia Thank you for taking the time to respond. I'll try it as soon as I get home. Otherwise, I'm doomed to use Java 8 :D. But it was for Android and it is now compatible so no big deal actually.

Comment: It does not work if I am trying to switch java version build within the same 1.8 or 1.7, for example, such as java 8 102 or java 8 171

Comment: Hi @HarveyLin. I don't know, as I'm not working with this since 2015 and I don't have this setup anymore. I'd suggest to set the specific java version on **step 7**, so it is `1.8.102` or `1.8.171`. Be cautious though, I don't know what side effects can this have. Please, let us know if this worked or share a solution if you find one.

Answer (score 25):

Since Java 1.6, a java.exe is installed into %windir%\system32 that supports a "-version" command line option.  You can use this to select a specific version to run, e.g.:

```
java -version:1.7 -jar [path to jar file]
```

will run a jar application in java 1.7, if it is installed.

See Oracle's documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Answer (score 6):

Once I updated my Java version to 8 as suggested by browser. However I had selected to uninstall previous Java 6 version I have been used for coding my projects. When I enter the command in 
"java -version" in *cmd*  it showed 1.8 and I could not start eclipse IDE run on Java 1.6.

When I installed Java 8 update for the browser it had changed the "PATH" System variable appending "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" to the beginning. Newly added path pointed to Java vesion 8. So I removed that path from "PATH" System variable and everything worked fine. :)

Answer (score 4):

Go to control panel --> Java
You can select the active version here

Comment: This has no effect with Java 7, the public JRE in `C:\Program Files` will always be used instead of your specified path.

Comment: Better to modify PATH variable if it is overwritten by another java installation.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is set the PATH environment variable in Windows to point to where your java6 bin directory is instead of the java7 directory.

Right click My Computer > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Environmental Variables

If there is a JAVA_HOME environment variable set this to point to the correct directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

Update your environment variables

Ensure the reference to java/bin is up to date in 'Path'; This may be automatic if you have JAVA_HOME or equivalent set. If JAVA_HOME is set, simply update it to refer to the older JRE installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 10 or windows server 2012, the steps to change the java runtime version is this:

1. Open regedit using 'Run'
2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> JavaSoft -> Java Runtime Environment
3. Here you will see all the versions of java you installed on your PC. For me I have several versions of java 1.8 installed, so the folder displayed here are 1.8, 1.8.0_162 and 1.8.0_171
4. Click the '1.8' folder, then double click the JavaHome and RuntimeLib keys, Change the version number inside to whichever Java version you want your PC to run on. For example, if the Value data of the key is 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171', you can change this to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_162'.
5. You can then verify the version change by typing 'java -version' on the command line.