# integration of FB into blackberry

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

i want to integration of FB into blackberry..plz tell me the steps. i have dwnloded FB sdk for BB and

then next how to get login and get the user ID and token id.how login to fb and directly go to our app

I've searched through all the topics related to my question but couldn't find a solution to it. I'm coding for a Blackberry app using the BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse v1.5.2 with JRE 7.1.0. I'm currently trying to integrate Facebook Connect into my app so that the users can log into our app through Facebook. The Blackberry Facebook SDK that I'm using is version 0.8.25 downloaded from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/

After getting the two jar files, FacebookBlackberrySDK-v0.8.25.jar and Log4B-v0.9.4.jar I first preverified them with eclipse successfully and included them into my project as libraries. The project compiled successfully but then I got a run time Uncaught exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
       Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);
this Facebook class not found but in jar package allredy it have.

plz help me..

thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your JRE 7.1.0 to JRE 6.0. It should work fine.
I also resolved this problem.

[See here for an explanation how.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333553/how-can-i-change-the-java-runtime-version-on-windows-7)